# How does touch tmp/db_syn.txt work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, passenger

I have a Ruby on Rails application which runs on Passenger. We have the following Capistrano task:

```
run "touch #{current_release}/tmp/sync_db.txt"
```

I would like to know how does this works. How does Passenger know that what source and destination databases needs to get synched? Where should I look for any configuration files?

Answer (score 1):

Passenger author here. Passenger does not sync databases, and does not know anything about sync_db.txt. Whatever sync_db.txt, it is handled by something else in your system.